# Classifying the cell contents in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

i have a Excel sheet containing a large number of rows (7500) and few (15) columns. The task for me to do now is i have to search a complete column cells for the presence of a specific word pattern (say shirt) and add a value to name it in the adjacent cell (say clothing). I've completed until this. But the issue is when i search again using the same formula for another word pattern (say apple) and enter its adjacent value as fruit; the cells already containing clothing were replaced by fruit if both apple and shirt available in that particular cell. i need both clothing and fruit to be displayed in the cell rather than a single value. I have to try different set of values. Help me completing this task.

Thanks !

Comment: Show your code, including how you're populating the cells with categories.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question I would use a formula like so

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("shirt",A1)),"","Clothing"),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("apple",A1)),"","Fruit"))
```

Where the formula is in B1. You can modify it to add spaces or comma's and such.